# Customize Bootstrap (sass) avoiding be overrided by someone else when packages are installed via Bower

Tags: gruntjs, bower, bootstrap-sass

I would like to know the best way to customize Bootstrap (sass) avoiding be overrided by someone else when packages are installed via Bower.

Let's say I have a project with Grunt, Bower and Bootstrap (sass).

In bower.json I have some dependencies as bootstrap-sass:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    ...
  }
}
```

Through Grunt I install all packages from the Bower dependencies, which are downloaded in the */bower_components* folder. Then all scss bootstrap files are copied from */bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets* to */sass*. I have a *main.scss* file in */sass* wich imports bootstrap (@import 'bootstrap';). Finally */sass/main.scss* is compiled into */css/main.css*. This is my Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        'bower-install-simple': {
            prod: {
                options: {
                    production: true
                }
            },
            dev: {
                options: {
                    production: false
                }
            }
        },

        bowercopy: {
            options: {
                srcPrefix: 'bower_components'
            },
            sass: {
                options: {
                    destPrefix: 'sass'
                },
                files: {
                    '_bootstrap.scss': 'bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss',
                    'bootstrap': 'bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/*.scss',
                    'bootstrap/mixins': 'bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/*.scss'
                }
            },
            ...
        },

        sass: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'css/main.css': 'sass/main.scss',
                }
            }
        },

        ...
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower-install-simple');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bowercopy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    ...

    grunt.registerTask('bower', ['bower-install-simple:dev', 'bowercopy']);
    ...
};
```

So I want to customize bootstrap. For example I want to modify some variables from */sass/bootstrap/_variables.scss* and remove some components from */sass/_bootstrap.scss*. The problem is when someone else installs packages via Bower and the customized bootstrap is overrided with the default one.

How could I keep my customized bootstrap without been overrided?